# Kibana 7.11 - index-pattern export not showing any fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have created an index-patter in kibana (7.11) in the UI and i can see all the fields configured correctly. But when i go to `Saved objects` and export it, it doesn't contain any fields

> {"attributes":{"fieldAttrs":"{}","fields":"[]"...

Is there something i am missing here?

I have another index-pattern created by journalbeat which exports correctly with all the configured fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Starting Kibana 7.11, index patterns as saved object contain no more field detail. The list of field is prepared on load.

Elastic added a changelog entry [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.11/release-notes-7.11.0.html) finally:

> In index pattern management - Refresh button removed as index pattern field lists are refreshed when index patterns are loaded, such as on page load or when moving between kibana apps

Comment: Have you find a way to export these fields? I’m trying to migrate a Kibana from one server to another so I need to export them on the old server and import them on the new one.

Comment: On the new server, you don't have to import fields. They will be added to index pattern automatically according to ES index targeted by the index pattern.